# Multiple tours with intro.js

Tags: javascript, intro.js

We'd like to have one general multi-page tour and also page specific tours available for a web app. The multipage one is functioning, and the page specific one also triggers, but calls both tour data objects. Is there a way to have multiple tours on the same page?

```
function initTours(){

// Start intro tour
document.getElementById('startIntro').onclick = function() {
    introJs().setOption('doneLabel', 'Next page').start('.intro-farm').oncomplete(function() {
        window.location.href = 'nav_season.php?multipage=true';
    });
};

var tourStep = $('.content .intro-farm').attr('data-step');
var nextLink = $('#nextTourLink').attr('href');
if (RegExp('multipage', 'gi').test(window.location.search)) {
    introJs().setOption('doneLabel', 'Next page').goToStep(tourStep).start('.intro-farm').oncomplete(function() {
        window.location.href = nextLink+'?multipage=true';
    });
} 

//Page specific
if ($('.page-tour').length > 0){
    //Page specific tour
    $('.pageHelp').on('click',function() {
        introJs().start('.page-tour');
    });
} else {
    $('.pageHelp').on('click',function(){
        $('#messageModal .row').html("<p>We don't have help tips for this page, but if you are stuck, please don't hesitate to <a href='#'>contact us</a>.</p>")
        $('#messageModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can have multiple tours in a same page but then you should check the url of page and make a condition and preventing calling the first tour again.

For example suppose your page is `boo.php`, then for the first tour you should check whether `window.location.pathname` is equals to `boo.php` or not, and then show the first tour to the user and after redirecting to the next page (e.g. `boo.php?anotherPage=true`) check the url of page again and show the next tour to him.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to define your steps using the [Programmatic way](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/example/programmatic/index.html), so you can define your steps as you want. If I understood you correctly your tours both capture all the steps, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following Code. It is working fine.

```
if (RegExp('multipage', 'gi').test(window.location.search)) {
    introJs().setOption('doneLabel',
         'Your next Page &rarr; (Name of Page)').start().oncomplete(function() {
        window.location.href = 'nextpage.html?multipage=true';
    });
}
```